# Python: Return value of an instance

Tags: python

This is a basic question, might flag this as a duplicate. I am overloaded with information over the past few days studying Intermediate Python and I forgot to remember the special method of class to get the value of class.

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Ninja Warrior"

    # add special method to return self.name as a default value of Example()

print(Example().name)
# Ninja Warrior

print(Example())  # This is what I want to do
# Ninja Warrior
```

Comment: Add an `__str__` method: `def __str__(self): return self.name`

Comment: No problem; this is a duplicate so feel free to delete your question.

Comment: I still think you should delete your question because answerers answering a question that has been asked before only adds noise to the site.

Comment: `You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it.`

Comment: Too late then, maybe next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `__str__(self)` method as following:

```
class Example():

def __init__(self):
    self.name = "Ninja Warrior"

# add special method to return self.name as a default value of Example()
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

print(Example().name)
# Ninja Warrior

print(Example())  # This is what I want to do
# Ninja Warrior
```

Working Ideone https://ideone.com/D48pwl

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `__str__`

```
class Example():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Ninja Warrior"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # add special method to return self.name as a default value of Example()

print(Example().name)
# Ninja Warrior

print(Example())  # This is what I want to do
# Ninja Warrior
```